# How do I save a function pointer for later use in c++, similar closures that have a saved state

Tags: c++, closures, function-pointers

I am a c++ newbie so I'm not sure how to write this, but basically I want a function that takes in a few parameters and returns a function pointer that does not need any parameters and can be executed for later use. Exactly like a closure.

I know c++ does not have closures, but can get some of the same effects with lambda expessions. I'm just not sure if it can do what I want it to do. Again I don't know much c++. I have been going through tutorials and reading posts about how lambdas work in c++, but I can't figure out how do get this code to work.

Here is some example code of what I'm trying to in typescript

```
let myVariable;

const myClosure = (param1: number, param2: number, param3, string, ) => {
    return () => {
        // Do something with params
        console.log(param1, param2, param3);
    }
}

function whereInitalized() {
    myVariable = myClosure(1,2,"name");

}

function whereExecuted() {
    myVariable(); // prints the params
}

whereInitalized();
whereExecuted();
```

This is what I want in c++, but it's wrong

```
// Not correct syntax or type
// Having trouble getting typing for this variable;
std::function<void(param1: T, param2: P, param3: V)> (*myVariable)() = myClosure;

std::function<void()> myClosure(param1: T, param2: P, param3: V) {
    return []() { // Returns a function that does not take a parameter
        param1.someMethod();
        param2->Call(blah, blah);
        // ... More work
        
    };
}

void functionWhereInitalized() {
    myVariable = myClosure(param1, param2, param3);
}

void functionWhereExecuted() {
    myVariable();
}
```

And here is what I have in c++, works, but cannot take in parameter

```
std::function<void()> myVariable = myClosure;

std::function<void()> myClosure() {
    return [num = 99]() mutable {
        // Test code to see it gets called
        num++; 
        std::cout << num << "  --  " << "\n";
    };
}

void functionWhereInitalized() {
    myVariable = myClosure();
}


void functionWhereExecuted() {
    myVariable();
}
```

I appreciate any responses in advance!

Comment: You say that you "don't know much c++". Unfortunately, the very first thing you will learn about C++ is that it is not about instant gratification. It takes time to learn it, a long time. You are describing one of the basic templates from the C++ library, but to get there it's necessary to study, and learn, core C++ fundamentals, for about a year or two, before reaching its advanced topics, like templates. Any attempt to short-circuit the process will, eventually, always end in tears. C++ is just too complicated to be learned by asking one question at a time, on Stackoverflow.

Comment: You were already close. You only have to transfer the parameter values into the closure. Just insert a `=` in the lambda introducer, so that it reads `[=]() {`... Of course, you also have to get the parameter syntax right, but that is really the topic of an introductory C++ tutorial.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would like to disagree. It might take some years to get C++ to the "professional software developer level", but you only need a little bit of that knowledge to actually get something done. And anyone with some programming experience should be able to get to a pretty good understanding of the language it in a matter of a few months.
Perhaps instead of wasting your time demotivating people willing to learn you should instead actually tell them what "basic templates from the C++ library" they are "describing"?!

Comment: Here's the problem, @NikitaDemodov: this is what's going to happen with the "little bit of that knowledge to actually get something done". You now get excited, and copy/paste the given answer and use it (I'm referring to YSC's answer). Great. You're excited. You're happy. You're so excited that you decided that you want to call the lambda a second time. Nothing happens. No error. Nothing. You tear your hair out. Finally, a day later, at your wits' ends, you resort to posting another question on Stackoverflow. Contrast that: you take time to learn C++ up front, then you just see why and fix it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I do totally agree with your sentiment. C++ - as most complicated things - needs a good foundation to really get going. And in this case the OP should definitely take a look at some introductory C++ tutorials. However, I found your comment to be discouraging of actually pursuing these fundamentals. It makes C++ sound like some dark whichcraft that only stereotypical neckbeards have a chance at using. Yet C++ is widely used by many people who have never programmed in their life (take Arduino-newbies as an example!).
I want to motivate OP to read a tutorial - not start a degree.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering the technical question, a note from Sam Varshavchik I agree with:

> You say that you "don't know much c++". Unfortunately, the very first thing you will learn about C++ is that it is not about instant gratification. It takes time to learn it, a long time. You are describing one of the basic templates from the C++ library, but to get there it's necessary to study, and learn, core C++ fundamentals, for about a year or two, before reaching its advanced topics, like templates. Any attempt to short-circuit the process will, eventually, always end in tears. C++ is just too complicated to be learned by asking one question at a time, on Stackoverflow.

Now for the technical question: you can acheive simple closures as described here with [lambda captures](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture)<sup>1</sup>:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

auto make_closure(std::ostream& out, std::string_view message, int repeat=1)
{
    return [&out,repeat,message]() mutable { while (repeat --> 0) out << message; };
}

int main(){
    auto say_hello = make_closure(std::cout, "Hello\n", 2);
    say_hello();
}
```

[Live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20add2016c5b5ecc)

---

<sup>1)</sup>

> The captures is a comma-separated list of zero or more captures, optionally beginning with the capture-default. The capture list defines the outside variables that are accessible from within the lambda function body. The only capture defaults are
>
> `&` (implicitly capture the used automatic variables by reference) and
> `=` (implicitly capture the used automatic variables by copy).
> The current object (`*this`) can be implicitly captured if either capture default is present. If implicitly captured, it is always captured by reference, even if the capture default is `=`. The implicit capture of `*this` when the capture default is `=` is deprecated. (since C++20)

Comment: You might wander where that `-->` _"goes to"_ comes from. This is a joke explained in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/5470596).

Answer (score 0):

```
std::function<void(param1: T, param2: P, param3: V)> (*myVariable)() = myClosure;
```

I'm not rly sure what's going on in here. my wild guess would be you want to do something like this

```
std::function<void()> yourClosure(T1 const& p1, T2 const& p2, T3 const& p3)
{
  return [p1, p2, p3]() { /* do the thing */};
}
```

but if you just want to store function for later use you can actually either

```
auto const function = [a,b,c](){ /* meaningful code*/ };
```

or

```
some_types... a, b, c; // whatever variables you have
auto const function_with_params = [](auto const& a, auto const& b, auto const&c){ /* skrnyr dgdyr */};
auto const function_with_bound_params = std::bind(function_with_params, a, b, c);
```

both lambda version and binding version should be cast-able to `std::function<void()>`